# How to merge changes from one branch to another after pushing to remote

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have a scenario were I have two branches master and testbranch as

```
Master <--M1 <--- M2 <-- M3

TestBranch...............M3 <-- T1 

New Master:

Master <--M1 <--- M2 <-- M3 <-- T1
```

I pushed the changes from the testbranch to the remote, now I want to merge my changes in testbranch to master branch. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you want to merge locally and not on the remote?
What are `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, and `T1`?
Which git service are you using on your remote? Is that `github`, `gitlab` or something else?

Comment: I want to merge it locally so that my changes could be peer reviewed before making into the master branch.

Comment: The peer review should be performed in the remote. The local modifications are only for you. How will your peer review your local changes? In Github you should create a pull request; on gitlab you should create a merge request, which is the same, so after review and approval your feature will be merged to the remote master. Locally what makes sense for you is to merge master into your branch, not the opposite.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague.
Do you just want to merge TestBranch into Master? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to merge Testbranch into master.

Comment: If it's a matter of reviewing what changes `TestBranch` introduces to `master`, then it makes sense that your branch is up to date with `origin/master` (supposedly the same branch that others contribute to) - that can happen either through a merge or through a rebase. From then on, a pull request or a merge request is just a formal step of showing the diff between your branch and `master` - and as already suggested, that doesn't need to happen on your machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using cherry-picking.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick <commit-id>
```

Comment: While cherry-picking (a) copies a commit (b) using Git's merge machinery, the resulting commit is not a *merge commit* and *is a copy of the original commit* (so is a different commit, with a different hash ID). If that is what you want, that's the right thing to do. But don't call this "merging" a commit; it's "cherry-picking", not merging. Using the wrong word here will eventually lead you astray. Git is notoriously user hostile and not being careful with words and actions in Git will lead to pain (I say this from experience :-) ).

Comment: Thanks for the wise comment. I wish I knew the difference between cherry-picking and merging before I posted this question.

Comment: What if you have 5 commits in your test branch?